# Can i use xml3d with stl models?

Tags: stl, xml3d

I'd really like to use STL models with XML3d.  Is there a way to convert back and forth between these formats?

Comment: Simply changing the question into a complete sentence with a few more words eliminates the need to pad it with meaningless lines. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can convert STL files to XML3D using the Blender exporter for instance:
https://github.com/ksons/xml3d-blender-exporter

Another option is to write a plug-in for STL files that allow to reference STL files from `<mesh>` and `<data>` elements:

```
<mesh src="foo/bar.stl"/>
```

This would be very similar to the existing plug-ins for MeshLab/JSON and OpenCTM files:

- http://xml3d.github.io/xml3d-examples/examples/meshlab/meshlab.html
- http://xml3d.github.io/xml3d-examples/examples/openctm/openctm.html

Answer (score 1):

We've just released a new converter that uses the [Open Asset Import Library](https://github.com/assimp/assimp) to convert many 3D formats (including STL) to XML3D's asset format:

https://github.com/csvurt/assimp2xml3d

It can't convert from XML3D back to other formats, but this might be something we add in the future.

Answer (score 1):

There is a plug-in for STL file now:
https://github.com/xml3d/xml3d-stl-plugin

It allows using STL files as simple as:

`<mesh src="../path/to/model.stl"></mesh>`