# Load XML3D models with AJAX/javascript (.stl or .json)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml3d

Is it possible to change the model from javascript/jquery/ajax? I managed only to visualize an .stl file (using the [xml3d-stl-plugin](https://github.com/xml3d/xml3d-stl-plugin) mentioned by [ksons](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1503969/ksons) on [Can i use xml3d with stl models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30165025/can-i-use-xml3d-with-stl-models/32883711#32883711)) or xml3d .json file using the basic xml3d.js on **get** request only. It would be nice to be able to choose a 3d model via ajax and visualize it.

Perhaps even better, if it was possible to use the file directly from the client (using HTML5 local files), like in http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/ (this way it could start visualizing the file selected by the user and in the same time upload the file to a server to do some business logic with it, which would save a lot of time).

Is any of the two solutions possible in any way? (preferrably using .stl files directly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is relatively easy using the [URL.createObjectURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) method:

```
<input id="upload" type="file"/>
<script>
    function handleFileSelect(evt) {
        var file = evt.target.files[0];
        $("mesh").attr("src", URL.createObjectURL(file));
    };
    document.getElementById('upload').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
</script>
```

I added this functionality to the xml3d-stl-plugin example: http://xml3d.github.io/xml3d-stl-plugin/examples/

Similar, you can create references from XHR.